# Combine rows with same column value if column value greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following `pd.DataFrame`:

```
    | x     | id
----|-------|-------
1   | 22    | 0
2   | 237   | 0
3   | 566   | 1
4   | 100   | 1
5   | 11    | 0
6   | 44    | 2
7   | 22    | 2
8   | 1445  | 0
```

I would like to obtain the following

```
    | x     | id
----|-------|-------
1   | 22    | 0
2   | 237   | 0
3   | 666   | 1
5   | 11    | 0
6   | 66    | 2
8   | 1445  | 0
```

where rows with a common `id` (only if `id > 0`) are squashed in a single row (where their `x`s are summed) and, for each unique id `i`, the index of the first row that had `id == i` is kept in the new `pd.DataFrame`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create helper `Series` for identify `0` values and assign unique values:

```
s = np.arange(1, len(df.index) + 1) * df['id'].le(0).astype(int)
print (s)
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    5
6    0
7    0
8    8
Name: id, dtype: int32

df = df.groupby(['id', s], as_index=False, sort=False)['x'].sum()
print (df)
   id     x
0   0    22
1   0   237
2   1   666
3   0    11
4   2    66
5   0  1445
```

If need use only consecutive values is necessary another `Series` for unique consecutives:

```
print (df)
      x  id
1    22   0
2   237   0
3   566   1
4   100   1
5    11   0
6    44   1
7    22   1
8  1445   0

s1 = np.arange(1, len(df.index) + 1) * df['id'].le(0).astype(int)
s2 = df['id'].ne(df['id'].shift()).cumsum()

df = df.groupby(['id', s1, s2], as_index=False, sort=False)['x'].sum()
print (df)
   id     x
0   0    22
1   0   237
2   1   666
3   0    11
4   1    66
5   0  1445
```